# Difference between $this.text and $this.value and why 1 returns a null value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with a script containing the lines below (top is commented out right now). They are in a loop to do a sum on the textboxes on a form. However, I get: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' when this runs. If I comment out the bottom line and uncomment the top line, it works fine.

I still want to keep the replace function though and I am not sure how to go about this.

```
total += $(this).text();

//difference and why the previous works, but the below returns null, but if

total += ($(this).all[0].value.replace(/\D/g, '')) * 1
```

EDIT: Should have mentioned that this was something I needed to debug and found this error.

Comment: What is `.all` ? Why not just `total += ($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '')) * 1`

Comment: Is the `$(this)` an input type text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` gets or sets the text inside an element.

For example: `<p>Hello World</p>`

`console.log($('p').text())` will return `Hello World`

`.value()` isn't a jquery method, instead use .val()

`.val()` is used to get or set the value of an input field.

For example `<input type="text">` If you wanted to get or set the value of the input, say on form submit, you would use something like `$('input').val()`

Comment: This was it. Edited my post too soon, but I didn't write this so thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `.text` does not exist as a property of a textbox. To retrieve its value, use `val()` (see 2)

**2.** You're mixing vanilla JS with your JQuery. `.value` should be `.val()`.

**3.** What are you trying to attempt with `.all`...? This is the *null* that your error is referring to.

**4.** I think this may be what you want:

```
var total = 0;

$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
   total += ($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '')) * 1
});

alert("Your total is " + total);
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31jna7r1/)

Comment: This was it. Edited my post too soon, but I didn't write this so thanks for helping!